# How to solve a formula on Python if one of the variables in the formula is an array of numbers?

Tags: python, numpy

I am extracting data from a file and then using this data to calculate some formulas. When I extract the variable "I" (which is all the row values for one column) and I use that variable to solve the formula "T" an error appears:

> TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

How can I apply a variable that represents an array to such formula?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter='    ')
Lt = data[1:,3]
print(Lt)
v= 1300
cn = (v-137.55)/10.58
print(cn)
round(cn)
V = 10.58*round(cn)+137.55
print(V)
I = data[1:,116]
print(I)
Ifunc = np.vectorize(I)
print(Ifunc)
x = 10**-12
print(x)
y = V**3
print(y)
T = (1.4387*V)/(np.log(1+1.191*x*(y/I), 10))
```

I expect to solve the formula for all the numbers in the array.

> TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType

Appears when I run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [np.log10()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log10.html#numpy.log10):

```
T = (1.4387*V)/(np.log10(1+1.191*x*(y/I)))
```